# Vue Firebase: router is undefined

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, vue-router, vite

I'm working on a Vue Firebase project and I'm getting an error that router is undefined. I've checked my code and I'm not sure what's causing this issue. Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

Here's my code:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");
const router = useRouter();

const signUp = (): void => {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), email.value, password.value)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Success");
        router.push("/feed");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.code);
        alert(error.message);
      });
};

const signInWithGoogle = (): void => {
  // Add your code to sign in with Google here
};

export default {
  name: "SignUp",
  setup() {
    return {
      email,
      password,
      router,
      signUp,
      signInWithGoogle,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I'm using Vue 3 and Firebase, and I've confirmed that my index.ts file is correctly exporting the router object. I'm not sure what else to check. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Review the Vue 3 composition syntax for the `setup()` function in the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state) as well as the [Vue-Router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html).  Your variables and functions should go inside the `setup()` function (hence why setup returns them).

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  name: 'SignUp',
  setup() {
    const email = ref('');
    const password = ref('');
    const router = useRouter();

    const signUp = (): void => {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), email.value, password.value)
        .then(data => {
          console.log('Success');
          router.push('/feed');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.code);
          alert(error.message);
        });
    };

    const signInWithGoogle = (): void => {
      // Add your code to sign in with Google here
    };
    return {
      email,
      password,
      router,
      signUp,
      signInWithGoogle
    };
  }
};
</script>
```